# How can I seal improperly installed vinyl tile joints?

Tags: tile, vinyl, sealant

I installed [lifeproof luxury vinyl tile](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lifeproof-Emerald-Bay-Marble-22-MIL-x-11-9-in-W-x-23-8-in-L-Click-Lock-Waterproof-Vinyl-Tile-Flooring-17-7-sq-ft-case-SI1910302L/327716113) in my bathroom and want to make extra sure the seams of the tiles are waterproof. I found the [Roberts 7500](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ROBERTS-8-oz-Vinyl-Seam-Sealer-for-Sheet-Flooring-7500-8/307565677) seam sealer but it dried white, and the "grout" lines of my tiles are dark gray.

Does anyone know of a clear option to seal vinyl tiles?

I was wondering if I could use silicone caulk...but something about that sounds like a bad idea to me. It needs to be robust to walking on and have flexibility for any movement in the flooring.

Of note, it's not actual grout but rather the edges of the tiles that click together. It's supposed to be waterproof but not all of the tiles perfectly clicked together so I wanted to be extra sure no water could get through.

Comment: HI Amanda, asking for a product recommendation is considered off-topic.  Asking for a solution is fine and people are free to recommend products.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally agree with RMDman, but in the case where you can't or aren't willing to correct the improper installation, I would consider a clear urethane sealant (or something like Lexel<sup>™</sup>, which claims extreme bond and good flexibility). It's about the only thing I'd call tough enough, yet flexible enough, to do the job. Silicone is too soft and doesn't bond well enough to last.

I suggest clear rather than a coordinating color because clear transmits the true color of the flooring, with all its variation, as "magic" giftwrap tape does.

You'd want to cut the nozzle in the smallest size possible and press firmly to limit application to just the narrow gap, then wipe away any excess. Note that urethane is *extremely* sticky, so you may want to actually mask precisely around the joint with tape first.

Answer (score 8):

**Do not** use any type of sealer in the seams.  It is not needed and will void any warranty from the manufacturer.

These type of floors work very well just as they are designed. Adding a sealer may increase your confidence, while actually decreasing the performance.

I have installed many of the LVP/LVT floors, even the one you mentioned exactly and never used any sealer, with the exception of at the perimeter, ( at baseboards and against cabinets)  I had perfect results. Never had a call back because of water infiltration in a kitchen or bath.

If the tiles are not perfectly clicked together, the issue is with the installation. Correct that rather than try to mask it.

(Side note:  I have found often the instructions of "tap" the tiles to get them to click together should really be "strike smartly or hard" to get them to click.  The correct tools are essential for a proper job as well.)

Comment: If the joints were not fully engaged in original installation, could one go back over the joints with the "correct tool" (rubber mallet?) and rectify or improve the fitting of the joints?

Comment: @ Jim Stewart,  Not all but some LVP/LVT can have the seams "flattened" with a rubber hammer.  The correct tools are a collection of tapping blocks, edge tapping tool,  Wedges and rubber hammer, as well as measuring and profile tools and a sharp razor knife and metal straight edge.

Comment: I wonder if you have advice for installing LVT around the door jamb and into a t strip transition as this difficulty is what led to the gaps. I used all those tools but ran into this problem around the door with the large tiles in a small space.

Comment: @ Amanda,  The best advice I can give about door frames, is to undercut the bottom and slide the plank or tile under.  I use a tile/plank scrap to guide the height of the cut and use a reciprocation ( vibrating) saw to make the cuts.